How to animate video appearance in Jetpack Compose
I want to create a basic proof of concept so that my app can render a combination of images and videos. Everything is working except the video, which does not have a fade-in animation and looks very jumpy. While the fade-out works fine, the fade-in does not.
Here is my code:
import androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView

enum class MediaType {
    IMAGE, VIDEO
}

data class Media(
    val url: String,
    val type: MediaType,
    val delay: Long
)

val media = listOf(
    Media("https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/flat-sale-landing-page-template_23-2149053848.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE, 5000),
    Media("https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/flat-sale-landing-page-template_23-2149053848.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE, 5000 ),
    Media("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4", MediaType.VIDEO, 16000),
    Media("https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/flat-sale-landing-page-template_23-2149053848.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE, 5000),
    Media("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4", MediaType.VIDEO, 16000),
    Media("https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/flat-sale-landing-page-template_23-2149053848.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE, 5000),
    Media("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4", MediaType.VIDEO, 16000),
    Media("https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/flat-sale-landing-page-template_23-2149053848.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE, 5000),
    Media("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4", MediaType.VIDEO, 16000),
    Media("https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/flat-sale-landing-page-template_23-2149053848.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE, 5000),
    Media("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4", MediaType.VIDEO, 16000),
)

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalTvMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DigitalSignageTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    shape = RectangleShape
                ) {
                    ContentPlayer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ContentPlayer() {
    var currentIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    fun switchToNextMedia() {
        if (currentIndex == media.size - 1) currentIndex = 0
        else currentIndex += 1
    }

    LaunchedEffect(currentIndex) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val currentMedia = media[currentIndex]
            delay(currentMedia.delay)
            switchToNextMedia()
        }
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        media.forEachIndexed { index, it ->
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = index == currentIndex,
                enter = fadeIn(tween(3000)),
                exit = fadeOut(tween(3000)),
            ) {
                if (it.type == MediaType.IMAGE) {
                    AsyncImage(
                        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                        model = it.url,
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                    )
                } else if (it.type == MediaType.VIDEO) {
                    VideoContentPlayer(it.url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun VideoContentPlayer(url: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setUri(url)
        .build()
    val exoPlayer = remember(context, mediaItem) {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .build()
            .also { exoPlayer ->
                exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
                exoPlayer.prepare()
                exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
                exoPlayer.repeatMode = ExoPlayer.REPEAT_MODE_OFF
            }
    }

    DisposableEffect(exoPlayer) {
        onDispose { exoPlayer.release() }
    }

        AndroidView(factory = {
            PlayerView(context).apply {
                player = exoPlayer
                useController = false
            }
        })
    
}

Now when you start it you can see that fade animation works for images but not for video when try to appear.

Can you add a recording so that people will easily see what's happening
